# How can I know which page triggered Session Start event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my session start event how can I know which page or handler triggered the Event?

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` for example.

Comment: With ASP.NET MVC this is going to be null, and I forget under what circumstances it can be with WebForms.

Comment: In SessionStart we already have HttpContext - so in general case - no, it won't.

Comment: @GrantThomas See nothing regarding `Request.Current` except it is `evil`; do see about `Session` - but that's not the question here. So you make it interesting to me, but I still don't see when `HttpContext.Current` is null in the `SessionStart`. All I can see is "not unittestable" - but nothing about null..

Comment: Maybe not the most definitive reference, just the first I found, and didn't look hard (indeed, didn't have to!) - basically there is variance in the utility of your answer, with no specifics on how and where it can be used, even though those conditions exist.

Comment: @GrantThomas Ok. I still don't see use case when `HttpContext.Current` is null in `Session_Start` - and it's really interesting that you are so sure in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this while creating session:

```
Path.GetFileName( Request.Url.AbsolutePath )
```